# Trying to carry a value across two html pages

Tags: php, html

I have a page with a table that allows to email regarding a piece of car accessories. For example, Volvo will have an exhaust, engine, interior, Vauxhall will have some same fields and some different etc.
I go to the Volvo section and click the exhaust department, it takes me to a form that I fill in and emails it to Volvo with the email message. However I am trying to pass the value from the first page to the parts section: e.g., if I click the exhaust, it will carry through to the form where the user can fill in contact info, the part in question will fill out from the button I have just clicked.

Here is my code (1st html page):

```
    <tr>
      <td><a href="infovolvo.html"><img src="images/volvo.jpg" alt="Volvo" width="140" height="50" align="Top"></td>
      <td>exhaust </td>
      <td align="top"><form action="volvo.html"><button type="submit" name="parts" value="6">exhaust</button></form></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="infovolvo.html"><img src="images/volvo.jpg" alt="Volvo" width="140" height="50" align="Top"></td>
      <td>interior</td>
      <td align="top"><form action="volvo.html"><button type="submit" name="parts" value="7">interior</button></form></td>
    </tr>
```

Then using this switch in my send form php file, I thought the value would carry over to the `volvo.html` and then through to the email but nothing is coming through:

```
switch($_POST['parts']){
    case 6:
    $email_message  = "wide exhaust";
    break;
    case 7:
    $email_message  = "dual exhaust";
    break;
}

$first_name      = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name       = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from      = $_POST['email']; // required
$maintelephone   = $_POST['maintelephone'];
$mobiletelephone = $_POST['mobiletelephone']; // not required
$address         = $_POST['address'];
$postcode        = $_POST['postcode'];
$dob             = $_POST['dob'];
$contact         = $_POST['contact'];

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Main Number: ".clean_string($maintelephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Mobile Number: ".clean_string($mobiletelephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";
$email_message .= "Postcode: ".clean_string($postcode)."\n";
$email_message .= "Date of Birth: ".clean_string($dob)."\n";
$email_message .= "Parts: ".clean_string($parts)."\n";
$email_message .= "Contact: ".clean_string($contact)."\n";
```

I of course have all the rest of the code required to send the email correctly, I just dont want to post it all to confuse anyone as to what sections I'm specifically having trouble with.

Comment: Using sessions sound like a solution if you must use more than one page

Comment: move the form outside your table. make your submit buttons check-boxes, have only one submit button in the end.

Comment: here is a good example of what you should change https://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/ i think if you make this small change you will not have a problem

Comment: @PeterDarmis I only have it in the table for organising the page layout and there is only one submit button at the end? I will try the suggested webpage advice though! thank you. *Mplungjan* I already have one value getting carried over for the company name and it works fine (If I choose volvo, It carries over and emails the subject line as the company name). I could try using sessions and see hoe it goes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case you have selections based on clicks in your 1st HTML, so it is better to use a hyperlink with `$_GET`, if you think it is safe to transfer the data via the address bar. Then in the second HTML page, you can simply fill in the transferred value in a hidden input of your form. Below is the reference code.

```
//This is 1st PHP where "sp" after "?" is short of Selected Part. You MUST use the value that will be stored in the DB or will be the Primary Key.
<a href="your_second_html_volvo.php?sp=Exhaust">Exhaust</a>

//2nd PHP - For instance selecting part of Volvo
<?php
    $selected_part = $_GET['sp'];
?>

<form action="your_action_script.php" method="POST">
    //Whatever details you want to collect
    <input type="text" name="customer_name" required>
    <input type="email" name="customer_email" required>

    //This is the Selected Part from the previous page
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_part" value=<?php echo "'" . $selected_part . "'" ?>>
</form>
```

Now you can easily call this selected value in your action script using `$selected_part = $_POST['selected_part']`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have got to the stage where it returns <?php echo $selected_part; ?> Any ideas on what I may have done wrong?

Comment: Now what is left? Calling it in the Action script?

Comment: I have got to the stage that the email is being sent but at my selected parts, I am getting the line <?php echo $selected_part; ?> whereas I assume my value (6) should be carried through and my switch should read the value 6 and print twin exhaust. It is bringing through the script instead of pulling through the number 6?

Comment: Although it was OK to use the previous code, but you can try the edited as well.

Comment: Vote down must be included with reasoning to help everyone improve.

Comment: Ok I figured what I was doing wrong, I should have replaced $email_message with $sp, sorry mohammed I don't understand what you mean, must be included with reasoning? Do you mean my reason for doing this? Thank you very much for your assistance, it now works perfectly. I am relatively new to programming so I appreciate the help that is available on stackoverflow

Comment: That was not for you. Someone has voted down the answer so I was saying to the person. I am glad to know that the solution worked. I myself praise StackOverflow a lot and try to be as helpful as possible. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I am not high enough reputation to vote it up as I have already tried.

Comment: It is fine. We look forward to your contributions as well.